# Access elements in a Python tuple

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I have a tuple like this:

```
('TRM',)
```

I would like to extract the string only from this tuple.

I did the following and it works but just thinking if there is a better way to do that.

```
>>> b = [x for x in a]
>>> b
['TRM']
>>> for i in b:
...  print(i)
...
TRM
>>>
```

Comment: What;s wrong with `for i in a: print(i)`

Comment: What is exactly the question here? Your question is very vague. Are all of the elements in your tuples strings or do they have different types? You want to iterate over them and do what? only access them or you want to manipulate them based on type?

Comment: Sorry if my question is vague. Currently, i convert the Tuple into a list and then iterate through the list to extract the string which i think it is incorrect. any way to extract the string directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
b = [x for x in a if type(x) == type("Str")]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a specific element of the tuple you can do it by index:

```
>>> a[0]
TRM
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking for but you could do:

```
for i in b:
    if isinstance(i, str):
        print(i)
```

and this will print

```
TRM
```

Edit: Now it checks whether an element is a string.